# Laravel 5 cacheTags path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is the use clause needed for cacheTags?

I have:

```
$categories = FinanceTransactionCategory::select('id')
            ->cacheTags(['cell-editors', 'categories'])
            ->remember(60)->get();
    $jsConfig['filters'] = [
        'category' => $categories
    ];
```

But it's not working because:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cacheTags()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been removed in Laravel 5. See here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7259

You'll want to use Cache directly now. This should help:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache#cache-tags

There's a discussion here that may be useful as well:

https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-remember-missing-from-query-builder

So I believe this (untested) code may do what you want:

```
$categories = Cache::tags(['cell-editors', 'categories'])->remember('categories', 60, function() {
    return FinanceTransactionCategory::select('id')->get();
});
```

Or at least get you going in the right direction!

Comment: So now if I wanted to cache my query how could I do it?

Comment: @imperium2335 Just updated my answer. It's a separate step at this point.

Comment: So I would just have to use an if statement to check if it's cached and if not run the query and add to cache?

Comment: @imperium2335 __exactly__

Comment: @imperium2335 Actually the cache `remember` method will check for an existing cache entry or store a new one, in one step. I just added some code to my answer. It's untested, but should be close to what you need at least. I'd suggest giving http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache a good read through.

Comment: @jszobody now I'm getting: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Cache\FileStore' does not have a method 'tags'

Comment: "Note: Cache tags are not supported when using the file or database cache drivers." From the cache documentation.

Comment: Do you really need tags for this? Maybe just use 'remember' with a key of 'categories' and drop the tags. That or change cache drivers.